# Elementor pro is changing a Woocommerce Shop Page title

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

When I have a shop page selected in WP (WooCommerce -> Settings -> Products) and enable Elementor Pro plugin and refresh the shop page, the page title displayed becomes the name of a product instead of the Title.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Here my page without Elementor Pro. Although the layout is messy, I can see the correct page title there.
   [image]
2. Select a page as a Shop Page.
   [image]
3. Enable Elementor Pro.
   [image]
4. Refresh the shop page. Now the page title became the name of a product.
   [image]

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Your Elementor title widget is pointing to "Post title", and it must be "Archive title". You have to edit the shop template in templates > theme editor.